# Need array assistance

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

I'm in a Java class and I'm having extreme difficulty getting started on the assignment. I do not want the answer but I really would appreciate any and all help on getting going and a basic outline of what to do.

> A supermarket wants to reward its best customer of each day, showing the customer’s name on a screen in the supermarket. For that purpose, the customer’s purchase amount is stored in an `ArrayList<Double>` and the customer’s name is stored in a corresponding `ArrayList<String>`.
>
> Implement a method
>
> `public static String nameOfBestCustomer(
>                    ArrayList<Double> sales, 
>                    ArrayList<String> customers)`
>
> that returns the name of the customer with the largest sale.
>
> Write a program that prompts the cashier to enter all prices and names, adds them to two array lists, calls the method that you implemented, and displays the result. Use a price of 0 as a sentinel.

Comment: There already is a basic outline of what to do from the last part of your question. Although you say you're not asking for the answer, you are. If you don't know what arraylists are - look these up.

Comment: So, where did you start and where is your problem? We are willing to give you assistance but you should show us some upfront effort you have made.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, but it does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Scanner to get the values that the cashier enters (an int for the purchase amount and a String for the customer's name, use conditions and throw exceptions to guarantee the values' types). Those values are put in two ArrayList (Lists of Integer and String).
Once the supermarket closes, you can use a loop on the list of purchases amounts to find the max purchase amount and its position in the list and use this position to find the best customer in the other list.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do :

```
package com.assignments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxSalesCustomer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      ArrayList<String> customerNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<Integer> customerSalesValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      String continueAdding = "Y"; 
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

      while(continueAdding.equals("Y")){
         System.out.println("Please Enter the customer Name:");
         String name = sc.next();
         customerNameArray.add(name);
         System.out.println("Please Enter the sales value:");
         Integer sales = sc.nextInt();
         customerSalesValue.add(sales); 
         System.out.println("Do you want to continue 'Y/N' ?" );
         continueAdding = sc.next();
     }

     String maxSalesCustomerName = getMaxSalesCustomerName(customerNameArray,customerSalesValue);
     System.out.println(maxSalesCustomerName);
  }

  public static String getMaxSalesCustomerName(ArrayList<String> customerNameArray,ArrayList<Integer> customerSalesValue){
    Integer maxValue = 0;
    String maxSalesCustomerName = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < customerSalesValue.size(); i++){
        if (maxValue < customerSalesValue.get(i)){
            maxValue = customerSalesValue.get(i);
            maxSalesCustomerName = customerNameArray.get(i);
        }
    }
     return maxSalesCustomerName;
   }

}
```